# Angular JS URL Validation

Tags: angularjs, html

We have to validate a value give by users for URL Field.

*System ask Facebook, Twitter, Google+ & etc*

Can anyone suggest us with best way.

*We are using the following pattern,*

```
/((?:https?\:\/\/www\.)|(?:[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$))/i
```

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you need to validate?

Comment: `(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})` try this

Answer (score 0):

You can start with using input type as `url`

example

```
<form name="form1" ng-controller="x">
    <label>Enter Site Name:</label>
    <input type="url" ng-model="initialwebsite" name="name" required />
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="form1.name.$error.required">
    You Can't Leave This Field Empty</span>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="form1.name.$error.url">
    Sorry Not a Valid URL, Don't Forget to Use http://</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

For further validation you can refer [this link](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)

As example, you can try this one

```
"#([a-z]([a-z]|\d|\+|-|\.)*):(\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?((\[(|(v[\da-f]{1,}\.(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~)|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)+))\])|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(:\d*)?)(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*|(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)){0})(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\xE000-\xF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\x00A0-\xD7FF\xF900-\xFDCF\xFDF0-\xFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?#iS"
```